# Receive Event Notification Broad-casted from Fortran in Managed Code

Tags: c#, fortran

I have a fortran (unmanaged code) dll as the calculation engine, and a C# form as the GUI.

Now, the calculation in fortran is long, so in order not to bore the users, I decided to use Asynch command to create a progress bar. The fortran dll would be responsible for putting messages in the progress bar as the calculation proceeds.

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement anoter function in Fortran dll that reports progress in numbers. For instance: "GetCalculationProgress" that returns two integers (current iteration and total number of iterations). You call that function periodically in another thread in your C# app and read those values. In Fortran you might have to use global variables to track those.

Besides, Here is a link that explains callback method:

http://xtechnotes.blogspot.com/2008/07/callback-to-c-from-unmanaged-fortran.html

Comment: Thanks, you have an example for this?

Comment: You don't need an example, just call that new method like you're calling the other calculation function in Fortran dll.

Comment: Take a look at this too: http://xtechnotes.blogspot.com/2008/07/callback-to-c-from-unmanaged-fortran.html

Comment: Your link is a nice one, can you put it in your main answer so that I can reward you appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Single responsibility: The UI shoul be responsible for display of the progress information, be it a progress bar or other visual effect. The Fortran should not be aware of how the information is displayed, rather it just emits "events" saying thinggs such "just started", "55%", "almost done" and "whoops that didn't work.

How do the events get passed? You probably need some kind of "buffering" tecnhology, perhaps using (named) pipes, or a message queue technology. Fortran can use C libraries so I guess that once you select a communication technology if that's not supported by Fortran directly  you can start by writing a bit of C and then get at that from Fortran.

Comment: Thanks, you have an example on how to do this?